# Hibernate/JPA: map<Object, Enum> manytomany is it possible?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, dictionary, enums, annotations

More specifically `(map<Course, Role>)((User) u).courses`

I have many `Course`s and many `User`s who have `Role`s in courses. A user might be staff in one course, and a student in another.

I have User entities with ID and course entities with ID, and a Role Enum type

I want a map belonging to user in order to query his role in a particular class:

```
public enum Role{ STUDENT, STAFF }


public class User ... {
...
@ElementCollection(targetClass=Role.class)
@CollectionTable(name="COURSE_ROLE")
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name="COURSE_ID")
@Column(name="ROLE_NAME")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Map<Course, Role> courses;
...
```

I have looked at several resources. ProJPA has the following:

```
@Entity
public class Department {
@Id private int id;
private String name;
// ...
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name="EMP_SENIORITY")
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name="EMP_ID")
@Column(name="SENIORITY")
private Map<Employee, Integer> seniorities;
// ...
```

if we consider a department as my user, and employee as my course this almost works, but I don't know how to handle the transition from their Integer to my Enum.

Please help me with the semantics of this table definition with annotations.

edit: To clarify, I had tried without the argument to ElementCollection(Role.class), and many other permutations of options but I don't feel I am grasping the situation. Currently, with this annotation combination I get an exception:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Map, at table: USER, 
for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(ROLE_NAME)]
```

Answer (score 1):

What I had works; I just needed to update my maven dependency hibernate version.